# Unable to get “OPEN” App banner with Ionic app and Universal Links

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, deep-linking

I am trying to implement [this plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-deeplinks) to get Universal links functionalities on my Ionic/Cordova app but I can’t accomplish completly.

On iOS simulator(14.5) when I do for example on a terminal:

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted https://my.domain.com
```

or

> "Create a calendar event with the link on Notes and click on it"

The app is opened correctly and the events has fired.

Then I put `https://my.domain.com` on the address bar in the safari browser and go but it not launch the app and not shows the “open in” app banner.

I know that if the universal link is fired **trought address bar browser not works but**, it should be show the “OPEN” banner no?

Something like this:

[image]

**I have discovered that if I focus on an input and keyboard is opened the banner appears but if I refresh page it disappears. Even if i pull down the top of the page the banner not appears.**

**I don’t know if its related but the website is also an ionic angular app**

Thanks for the help.

My setup:

Plugin installed with this command:

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=myapp --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=my.domain.com
```

-On https://my.domain.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association have this file:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "MYTEAMID.com.my.bundleid.com",
                "paths": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is mandatory to have the file on host root both?

-The AASA validator http://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator **returns all checks to OK.**

-On my config.xml have:

```
<config-file parent="com.apple.developer.associated-domains" target="*-Debug.plist">
        <array>
            <string>applinks:my.domain.com</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>
    <config-file parent="com.apple.developer.associated-domains" target="*-Release.plist">
        <array>
            <string>applinks:my.domain.com</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>
```

-Other environment info:

```
cordova-ios 6.2
cordova-cli: 10.0.0
ionic-angular: 5
```